# SQLite in Gluon Client Plugin Project

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I need to use SQLite in my Gluon Mobile Project on all platforms (iOS, Android, Desktop). I’ve found following question [SQLite on Android via JavaFX and Gluons client-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63375536/sqlite-on-android-via-javafx-and-gluons-client-maven-plugin) but unfortunately it didn’t help me. It would be really helpful to have a complete Maven pom.xml file, which contains SQLite binding for all platforms.

Is using of the SQLite the same as in the old jfxmobile plugin?

I mean following code:

```
private void loadDBDriver(){
        try {
        Class c = null;
        if (Platform.isAndroid()) {
            c = Class.forName("org.sqldroid.SQLDroidDriver");
        } else if (Platform.isIOS()) {
            c = Class.forName("SQLite.JDBCDriver");
        } else if (Platform.isDesktop()) {
            c = Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } else if (System.getProperty("os.arch").toUpperCase().contains("ARM")) {
            c = Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        }
    }
```

Update:

My pom.xml file looks as following. Sqlite integration relevant parts are

`<resourcesList>` and `<jniList>`

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-view-fxml-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Mires</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <javafx.version>15</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.9</attach.version>
        <connect.version>2.0.1</connect.version>
        <client.plugin.version>0.1.35</client.plugin.version>
        <sqlite.platform>Mac</sqlite.platform>
        <sqlite.arch>x86_64</sqlite.arch>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.5</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>com.kojojo.mires.Mircom</mainClassName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>glisten-afterburner</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect</artifactId>
            <version>${connect.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tukaani/xz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tukaani</groupId>
            <artifactId>xz</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.44-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>browser</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>orientation</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>gluon-releases</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${client.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${client.target}</target>
                    <resourcesList>
                        <list>org/sqlite/native/${sqlite.platform}/${sqlite.arch}/.*</list>
                    </resourcesList>
                    <jniList>
                        <list>org.sqlite.core.DB</list>
                        <list>org.sqlite.core.NativeDB</list>
                        <list>org.sqlite.BusyHandler</list>
                        <list>org.sqlite.Function</list>
                        <list>org.sqlite.ProgressHandler</list>
                        <list>org.sqlite.Function$Aggregate</list>
                        <list>org.sqlite.Function$Window</list>
                        <list>org.sqlite.core.DB$ProgressObserver</list>
                    </jniList>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader</list>
                        <list>com.kojojo.mires.views.MainMenuPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.kojojo.mires.views.AboutPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.kojojo.mires.views.AddConnectionPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.kojojo.mires.views.AddUnitPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.kojojo.mires.views.ConnectionSettingsPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.kojojo.mires.views.EditConnectionPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.kojojo.mires.views.EditUnitPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.kojojo.mires.views.JsonPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.kojojo.mires.views.UnitPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.kojojo.mires.views.UnitSettingsPresenter</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.Button</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.Label</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <client.target>host</client.target>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>display</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>util</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>ios</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>android</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for GluonSQLite: [The GluonSQLite App.](https://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gluonsqlite/)

Sample source code is available in this GitHub repository [gluon-SQLite.](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/gluonmobile5/gluon-SQLite)
I have been working with that for over years already.

Comment: The sample uses the old jfxmobile Gradle plugin. I meant the new gluon client Maven plugin.  (https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_the_gluon_client_plugin_for_maven)

Comment: It will be a good idea if you share what you have tried together with pom files. Anyway, have you check the answer from José Pereda in this link: https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/741

Comment: I only try with Gradle dependency management, It is believed that It will be an issue about configure for platform specific.